# FOC Clarke Transform multiplication coefficent

Tags: motordriver

I'm confused about the FOC Clarke Transform. I understood the transform principle from 3 phase stationary frma to 2 phase stationary frame. And it is a easy trigonometric calculation. I'm doing it like the attached image.

[My Clarke Transform Calculation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJubg.jpg)

But all the books, application notes are doing it like the following equations which is 2/3 times of my result.
Ialpha = Ia
Ibeta = (1/sqrt(3)) (Ia + 2Ib)

Total MMF is 3/2 times larger then the MMF of a phase. So i think my calculation is correct. Similar mismatch is exist at Inverse Clarke transform.
What is my mistake?
Thanks in advance.